# Ставить ли запятую в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

*Что делать, если вас сбил самокат **и** почему владельцы этих транспортных средств приравнены к пешеходам?*
Ставить ли запятую после слова «самокат»? Склоняюсь, что да...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Что делать, **если вас сбил самокат,** и почему владельцы этих транспортных средств приравнены к пешеходам?*

С одной стороны, запятая перед соединительным союзом "и" в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят вопросительные предложения: *Это кто такие и что им надобно?* (А. Пушкин).

С другой — нам надо закрыть запятой придаточное предложение (*если вас сбил самокат*), относящееся только к первой части. Поэтому запятая **ставится**.

Если бы придаточное отсутствовало, то перед "и" знака бы не требовалось:
*Что делать **и** почему владельцы этих транспортных средств приравнены к пешеходам?*

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы думаете о том, что запятая не ставится при вопросительных подпредложениях, разделенных сочинительными союзом, то есть такое, но придаточное: «если вас сбил самокат» — обособляется как условное придаточное; поэтому да, запятая после «самокат» ставится. Если вы думаете, что есть такое правило, которое отменяет запятые между сложносочиненным, даже если они относятся к обособляемым оборотам или придаточным, то такого правила нет.